# How to use XBM image data in Python without referencing external file

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I've been searching with every combination of keywords I can think of but I can't find an article that addresses this.

I'm building a Python Tkinter application (Python 2.7.x, Win 7) which includes buttons with image data (drawn from XBM files).  For example,

```
self._ResetIcon  = tk.BitmapImage(file='ResetIcon.xbm')
self._Reset      = tk.Button(self,
                             width=20, height=20,
                             image=self._ResetIcon,
                             command=self._reset)
```

Now I'm 99.9% sure there's a way to include the XBM image data as a declaration of some kind directly in the Python module itself, rather than pulling it from the external file.  But I can't find anything online that describes how to do it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: the option you're looking for is `data`: tk.BitmapImage(data=...)`. Then, just store the contents of the bmp file in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some more digging via Google and found it.

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm

> An X11 bitmap image consists of a C fragment that defines a width, a
>   height, and a data array containing the bitmap. To embed a bitmap in a
>   Python program, you can put it inside a triple-quoted string:
>
> ```
> BITMAP = """
> #define im_width 32
> #define im_height 32
> static char im_bits[] = {
> 0xaf,0x6d,0xeb,0xd6,0x55,0xdb,0xb6,0x2f,
> 0xaf,0xaa,0x6a,0x6d,0x55,0x7b,0xd7,0x1b,
> 0xad,0xd6,0xb5,0xae,0xad,0x55,0x6f,0x05,
> 0xad,0xba,0xab,0xd6,0xaa,0xd5,0x5f,0x93,
> 0xad,0x76,0x7d,0x67,0x5a,0xd5,0xd7,0xa3,
> 0xad,0xbd,0xfe,0xea,0x5a,0xab,0x69,0xb3,
> 0xad,0x55,0xde,0xd8,0x2e,0x2b,0xb5,0x6a,
> 0x69,0x4b,0x3f,0xb4,0x9e,0x92,0xb5,0xed,
> 0xd5,0xca,0x9c,0xb4,0x5a,0xa1,0x2a,0x6d,
> 0xad,0x6c,0x5f,0xda,0x2c,0x91,0xbb,0xf6,
> 0xad,0xaa,0x96,0xaa,0x5a,0xca,0x9d,0xfe,
> 0x2c,0xa5,0x2a,0xd3,0x9a,0x8a,0x4f,0xfd,
> 0x2c,0x25,0x4a,0x6b,0x4d,0x45,0x9f,0xba,
> 0x1a,0xaa,0x7a,0xb5,0xaa,0x44,0x6b,0x5b,
> 0x1a,0x55,0xfd,0x5e,0x4e,0xa2,0x6b,0x59,
> 0x9a,0xa4,0xde,0x4a,0x4a,0xd2,0xf5,0xaa
> };
> """
> ```
>
> To create X11 bitmaps, you can use the X11 bitmap editor provided with
>   most Unix systems, or draw your image in some other drawing program
>   and convert it to a bitmap using e.g. the Python Imaging Library.
>
> The BitmapImage class can read X11 bitmaps from strings or text files:
>
> ```
> bitmap = BitmapImage(data=BITMAP)
> bitmap = BitmapImage(file="bitmap.xbm")
> ```

Comment: You only addressed half the problem. Your answer would be better if you also showed how to use this data to create an image.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I don't follow. The string is simply the content of a typical XBM file, although with some reformatting for readability -- what more needs explained?  (I think it's fair to assume that the reader understands what an XBM file is and how to create/edit one.)

Comment: You need to translate that data into an actual image that is displayed on the screen. That is what the OP is asking how to do. For example: `image = tk.BitmapImage(data=BITMAP)`

Comment: @BryanOakley, it's there already, at the bottom of the block quote.  (I edited the answer to add that bit shortly after I created the answer -- it might have been at the same time you were putting in the comment.)

Comment: The link http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm is dead?

Comment: @abulka, you're right.  Unfortunately that's a hazard of a four year old answer ;).  However the quoted text inline covers the important information, what is lost is the proper crediting for the individual who provided it.